Is there some conditions to get Price of Midas, or is it just really, really, rare?
I've been in 70+ Nights, and used Changes of Fate tons of times, but only saw Price of Midas once in the Well of Charon, and without enough Life to buy it at that.
People online seem to say that it really is just rare, even in the first game, but might there be conditions attached to finding it? Health below a certain percentage, Gold under a certain value, or something else related?

From "SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Hades II\Content\Scripts"
And from "ConsumableData.lua" and "StoreData.lua" in that folder, it seems that it's treated as a healing item:
ConsumableData.lua:
DamageSelfDrop = 
    {
        InheritFrom = { "BaseWellShopConsumable", },
        Icon = "Shop_Gold_Blood",
        HideWorldText = true,
        PayoutPerHealthPoint = { BaseMin = 1.1, BaseMax = 1.8 },
        NotEnoughCurrencyVoiceLines = HeroVoiceLines.NotEnoughHealthVoiceLines,
        DropMoneyDelay = 0,
        Cost = 0,
        HealthCost =
        {
            BaseMin = 10,
            BaseMax = 30,
            AsInt = true,
        },
        UseText = "UsePurchaseLoot",

        OnPurchaseSound = "/SFX/StabSplatterSmall",
        OnPurchaseGlobalVoiceLines = "PurchasedDamageSelfDropVoicelines",

        ExtractValues =
        {
            {
                Key = "HealthCost",
                ExtractAs = "TooltipHealthCost",
            },
        }
    },

StoreData.lua:
StoreData =
{
    RoomShop =
    {
        -- @ for testing specific items, see FillInShopOptions() or ShowSurfaceShopScreen()
        MaxOffers = 3,
        HealingOffers =
        {
            Min = 1,
            Max = 1,
            WeightedList =
            {
                {
                    Name = "ArmorBoostStore",
                    Type = "Consumable",
                    Weight = 0.2,
                },
                {
                    Name = "DamageSelfDrop",
                    Type = "Consumable",
                    Weight = 0.2,
                },

So Price of Midas should be as rare as Splintered Shield, the Armor booster Well item, and "StoreLogic.lua" doesn't seem to have any preference when it calls "storeData.HealingOffers.WeightedList", as far as I can tell right now.
Lastly, "Fateful Twist", a.k.a "RandomStoreItem" doesn't have all of the HealingOffers in its possibilities, as ConsumableData says, only some Traits and Consumables. Other things that Fated Twist can't do are "Spark of Ixion", "Danaid Dagger", "Archaic Seal", among others.
So buying Fateful Twist won't luck into Price of Midas.
In any case, I got in the Post-Scylla Well of Night 87, after using the Fountain to get to like ~150 / 200 HP before the purchase and at 191 Gold.

According to this Steam Discussions page, there are no pre-requisites.

As far as I know, no prerequisite. And it doesn't say there is one in the codex either. You might be just unlucky (or it's more rare than the rest, since you pay with HP instead of gold).
Also I am pretty sure that I had that one in the Well once even when I didn't have enough HP to pay for it, so having enough HP doesn't seem to be a requirement.
 - Nikolaus

